# Matlab figure: Keeping same font when opening matlab figure window

Tags: matlab, plot, latex, matlab-figure

I want to use the latex font in a figure or pdf exported from Matlab.

When I create the figure with the attached script in a matlab livescript, in the output it shows the figure on the right. There the font is the right one. Then on the right above the figure in the output there is this button with the arrow "Open in figure window", then the window in the screenshot on the left appears and the font is wrong.

How do I keep the latex font in the figure window and then also if I export to a pdf or svg?

Alternatively as in the end I need to have a pdf of the figure: Can I directly export the diagram to a pdf file with a specific size? I just go the way with the figure window to rescale the diagram without loss of quality. How could I directly export a pdf file of the figure in the size of let's say 15 cm width and 10 cm height?

```
fontname = 'Latin Modern Roman'; 
set(0,'DefaultAxesFontName',fontname,'DefaultTextFontName',fontname);

sun = dataset.sun
time = linspace(0,10,length(sun))

fig = plot(time, sun, 'LineWidth',3)

xlabel('Time [d]', 'FontName', 'Latin Modern Roman', 'FontSize', 35); 
ylabel('Solar Irridiance [W/m^2]', 'FontName', 'Latin Modern Roman', 'FontSize', 35); 
set(gca, 'FontName', 'Latin Modern Roman', 'FontSize', 25);
```

[image: plot compare]

Comment: In the meantime the guys from Matlab were able to help me. If anyone is interested in the solution, here is the link: https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/2011932-matlab-figure-keeping-same-font-when-opening-figure-in-matlab-figure-window?s_tid=mlc_ans_email_view